# Query codeigniter inserts only 1 in mysql DB with bit data type

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Hi i'm having problems with this queries, when i run the CI query, this inserts only '1' in all the columns, i tried running the query directly in `phpmyadmin` and do the same,then i inserted data by phpmyadmin and this create a different query and inserted correctly.
This is created by phpmyadmin:

```
INSERT INTO `estancias`.`instalacion` (`idINSTALACION`, `sala_lactantes`, `sala_maternales`, `sala_preescolar`, `sala_usos_mult`, `a_recepcion`, `a_administrativa`, `sillas`, `archiveros`, `cuna_observacion`, `basc_estadimetro`, `botiquin`, `s_atencion_cunas`, `colchonetas`, `mesas_sillas_infantiles`, `muebles_guarda`, `area_lactancia`, `cocina_com_desp`, `consultorio`, `inst_sanitarias_ninos`, `inst_sanitarias_personal`, `area_juegos`, `area_educacion_preescolar`, `ventilacion`, `iluminacion`, `agua_potable`, `espacio_ninos`) VALUES (NULL, b'1', b'1', b'1', b'1', b'1', b'0', b'0', b'0', b'0', b'0', b'0', b'0', b'0', b'0', b'0', b'0', b'0', b'0', b'0', '', b'0', b'0', b'0', b'0', b'0', b'0');
```

And this by codeigniter with the data from $_REQUEST and setted into $instalacion:

```
$this->db->insert('instalacion',$instalacion);

INSERT INTO `instalacion` (`sala_lactantes`, `sala_maternales`, `sala_preescolar`, `sala_usos_mult`, `a_recepcion`, `a_administrativa`, `sillas`, `archiveros`, `cuna_observacion`, `basc_estadimetro`, `botiquin`, `s_atencion_cunas`, `colchonetas`, `mesas_sillas_infantiles`, `muebles_guarda`, `area_lactancia`, `cocina_com_desp`, `consultorio`, `inst_sanitarias_ninos`, `inst_sanitarias_personal`, `area_juegos`, `area_educacion_preescolar`, `ventilacion`, `iluminacion`, `agua_potable`, `espacio_ninos`) VALUES ('1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0');
```

Thank you by advance for your participation!

Comment: I think your problem is id remains 1 for all records?

Comment: In all the records are 1, but i'm not sure if is for that reason, cause actually adding the NULL of the AUTO_INCREMENT still doing the same. I guess could be part of the data type BIT, but only i'm guessing.

Comment: MAKE YOUR COLUMN `integer(11) auto-incemented primary key` and in your php query skip that field. that field will automatically handled.

Comment: Could You please show me your table structure ..???

Comment: `idINSTALACION  int(11) NO  PRI  NULL auto_increment
sala_lactantes  bit(1) YES   NULL 
sala_maternales  bit(1) YES   NULL 
sala_preescolar  bit(1) YES   NULL 
sala_usos_mult  bit(1) YES   NULL 
a_recepcion  bit(1) NO   NULL 
a_administrativa  bit(1) NO   NULL 
sillas  bit(1) NO   NULL 
archiveros  bit(1) NO   NULL 
cuna_observacion  bit(1) NO   NULL 
basc_estadimetro  bit(1) YES   NULL`   and all the table is using data type bit.

Answer (score 0):

You may select `varchar2` data type for all field except the `id` which must be `integer`.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($_REQUEST as $key => $value){
           $instalacion->$key=(bool)$value;
        }
```

This was the problem, always you have to convert to bool cause if leave the data without convert this still like a `STRING` and gives problems.

Hope someone else help this!